# Broadcast to Icecast / SHOUTcast with Objective-C, C, or C++

Tags: objective-c, audio, broadcast, shoutcast, icecast

I want to provide audio data into SHOUTcast or Icecast servers without using their own broadcaster, since i will be using this on various platforms including mobile.

I need protocol descriptions, open source projects, or samples to be able to send audio data (from mic or file) using Objective-C, C or C++ to SHOUTcast and Icecast servers.

Where can I find the information needed to build a proper SHOUTcast/Icecast source client?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Comment:  It's about time someone makes a SHOUTcast source client for mobile.  I've been needing this for a while, but don't have time to build it, so kudos to you.  Please make an Android version at some point.*

The first thing you should do is [download Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

Start the packet capture, fire up a SHOUTcast server, then fire up a source client, and connect it to the server.  Be prepared for the horrifying simplicity of this protocol.

### Primary Audio Protocol

1. Source client connects to SHOUTcast with TCP.  Use the port one up from the base port.  For instance, if your base port is 8000, your listeners connect on 8000 and you will connect on 8001.
2. Once connected, the SHOUTcast server won't say anything.  Just send the broadcast password, followed by a new `CrLf` (or `\r\n`).
3. If the password is wrong, it will say `invalid password` or something like that.  If it is correct, you're going to get something like this:

   `OK2`

   `icy-caps:11`

   Note that each line has `CrLf` after it, and after these two headers are sent, there are a pair of `CrLf`.
4. Now, it is up to the source client to send a bunch of headers:  `icy-name`, `icy-genre`, `icy-pub`, `icy-br`, `icy-url`, `icy-irc`, `icy-icq`, `icy-aim`, `content-type`.  Send them like this:

   `icy-name:My Awesome Station`

   Each line should be followed by `CrLf`, and after you're done sending all of the headers, send a pair of `CrLf`.
5. Once this is all done, start sending your stream data!  No need to start in any particular spot, just send data.  It is up to the clients on the receiving end to sync to the frame.  The SHOUTcast server is completely "dumb" to the traffic flowing through it.  You can connect with a Telnet client and send a bunch of text if you wanted to.

### Updating Metadata

So, you're probably wondering how you send information for the next track and what not.  The funny thing is, this is completely out-of-band from the connection where you send audio data.

All you have to do is make a web request to the port base (8000 in our example):

```
http://yourserver:8000/admin.cgi?pass=yourpassword&mode=updinfo&song=your%20song&url=some_url_goes_here_but_hardly_any_clients_use_it
```

In case that is difficult to read, these are the parameters:

- pass
- mode
- song
- url

You'll note that these same parameters, and others, can all be found in the SHOUTcast admin panel.

Comment: Thank you! Is this protocol same with Icy servers? (Is it a standartized protocol?) I will start implementing this after discovering audio conversion to adts.

Comment: ICY is SHOUTcast.  Yes, it should work with Icecast as well.  There is no written standard, but it is standardized in the way that everything uses it.

Comment: @RayFrand, I should note that with Icecast, while you can use this source protocol, you can only use one per server.  If you want to write a pure Icecast source, see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9985297/362536

Comment: @Brad thanks! this actually helped me aswell :D , my motive is a web-based shoutcast broadcaster [ so that broadcast off cloud ]

Comment: I was quite wondering what is the frame rate to broadcast to shoutcast ? I mean i can transcode mp3 files [ mine works as an async process this kinda makes it messy ] so i am wondering if there is any defined data rate that is to broadcasted to the server ? or can it handle anything

Comment: @Abhishek, The bitrate is not pre-defined, and varies from station to station, by preference of the owner.  If you can afford more bandwidth and wish to provide higher quality audio to your listeners, then go for it.  It is very common to provide a variety of bitrates, to accommodate those with slower connections.

Comment: No no no you got me wrong i was actually confused with how much data to send to shoutcast itself ! now i think i will send it just enough data to make it upto 44100 samples per second. Considering shoutcast is totally dumb with traffic it should just re-broadcast the data to clients ? Or should i actually send more data then this ?

Comment: @Abhishek, The data you send is the data that gets sent to clients.  The bitrate you choose to send to SHOUTcast is the bitrate that will be sent to clients.

Comment: Please note that this is only valid for SHOUTcast, Icecast works not like that, although it uses some of the icy headers.

Comment: @ePirat Yes, that's correct.  For Icecast see this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215019/icecast-2-protocol-description-streaming-to-it-using-c-sharp/9985297#9985297

Comment: @Brad Please note that even the linked post isn't at the most up to date state and some of the things there are not recommended practice anymore, like out of band metadata.

Comment: Here is the source client: https://github.com/fatihsokmen/android-icecast-broadcast

Answer (score 1):

I developed shoutcast wrapper native C files along with a sample android app that you can stream from device microphone -> [android-icecast-broadcast](https://github.com/fatihsokmen/android-icecast-broadcast).

It is captures, encodes pcm audio from mic. and broadcasts ice server.

Comment: Hi Fatih, I just saw your github repo. I want to broadcast mp3 from my android phone to icecast server. I have built my server but could not find any solution for android app. And I am unable to use your repo for this purpose. Can you guide me how to include it in my test project?

Comment: Your lib is amazing, works fine using Icecast, but when I try to run using shoutcast configs nothing happens