# Icecast sourcing library which may be used in a commercial program?

Tags: android, audio, icecast

I'm searching the net for an Icecast server sourcing library which I can use in my commercial program. Anything under LGPL, MIT or even a commercial license?

So far I was only able to find the libshout and BassEnc. The later may be purchased but I need to use it on Android 2.1+ and that is not the case with Bass (it expects 2.3+)

Thanks

Comment: Getting data to the Icecast/SHOUTcast server is trivial.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9241620/362536)  All you really need is a codec.  Which codec did you plan to use?  MP3?  AAC?  OGG?  It is not possible to answer your question until this is known.

Comment: @Brad hey, thanks for your answer. I was just looking for something to plug in and avoid the need to go low level network communication. However, since the protocol is that trivial I'm going to implement a network library by myself. Thanks!