# Library to retrieve SHOUTcast metadata in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, metadata, shoutcast

Can someone recommend the best library to retrieve SHOUTcast and Icecast metadata in C or C++? I've looked around but can't seem to find a good library. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this, but it might point you in the right direction:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239022/broadcast-to-icecast-shoutcast-with-objective-c-c-or-c

Comment: Shoutcast and Icecast handle this differently.  Are you acting as the client or the server?

Comment: @jeremy, the client (hence "retrieve")

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find it yourself, you could try to make your own, based on documentation, you just need to parse the stream, Headers, get the protocol, then there is a field, which tells you the length of each "sound" frame, followed for some meta-data frame, and then again, sound frame.

Here is some information of how shoutcast/icecast works. Hope it helps!

http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html