# Connect to Shoutcast V1 Socket C++

Tags: c++, sockets, shoutcast

Whether it is possible to connect like socket using C++ with shoutcast v1?
Or is the library to do it?

I read http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=348848 and but it didn't help me - connect failed.

Comment: Are you trying to play the stream or make a source client?  It's just a regular TCP connection.  For regular clients, it's very similar to HTTP.

Comment: Trying to connect to a SHOUTcast server v1 by means of socket. However, the connection fails.

Comment: If the socket connection fails, something else is wrong.  Check your firewall and what not.

Comment: Whether the SHOUTcast server sends some information after connect?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Are you trying to stream audio data from SHOUTcast, or send audio data to it?  Are you able to successfully create a TCP connection, or does that connection fail?

Comment: Trying to connect to a server to send audio data to it. Currently I have a problem with the connection, I do not know how to send password to server. Immediately after the connect?

Comment: That's correct.  As soon as you are connected, send the password and `\r\n`.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9241620/362536

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to connect with the password. But when I send information eg "icy-name: Server name", nothing changes. I need to send audio data?

Comment: Once you send all of your ICY headers, send an extra `\r\n` and then start sending audio data from your encoder.  Use Wireshark or some other packet sniffer to verify what is happening.

Comment: Thanks! And how to send audio data? Open audio like open() and send byte by byte ?

Comment: Yes, but send whole buffers at a time, to optimize transmission.

Comment: Can You could show me an example?

Comment: No unfortunately, I am not a C++ coder.  And, it would depend on what API you were using anyway.

Comment: I understand. And if this way is ok: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=348848?

Comment: Yes, that method looks correct.

Comment: Cool. And if I need encoder like lame?

Comment: Yes, you definitely need a codec of some sort.  You can either interface directly or use STDIO.  Also, check out FFmpeg.