# Streaming Audio with Icecast Protocol using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, server, icecast

Is it possible to use Objective-C to broadcast audio using the Icecast protocol?

For Node.JS I've found the library [nicercast](https://github.com/stephen/nicercast/blob/master/index.js) which seems to work pretty well. Is there an open-source equivalent for Objective-C or do I have to implement the protocol myself?

If I'll have to implement the protocol myself, then what do I need to know?
From the Node.JS Library I've seen that essentially, the server broadcasts an MPEG-stream using a normal web server and just sending the raw data over to the client.

Does this MPEG stream contain the metadata or do I have to send it separately?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear, you're not actually trying to make a source client for Icecast... you're trying to build an HTTP progressive streaming server that is compatible with Icecast/SHOUTcast in Objective C?

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239022/broadcast-to-icecast-shoutcast-with-objective-c-c-or-c?rq=1  Also, these days Icecast supports a simple HTTP PUT request.  I recommend going that route.

Answer (score 1):

Why not stream **to** an Icecast server instead? It's small enough to even run on embedded devices without big issues.
The nicercast implementation is **nowhere close** to being *"Icecast compliant"* as they claim.
If you want to know why, look at the Icecast sources or e.g. the supported formats.

I know it's en vogue to reinvent the wheel, badly and incompletely. But I'm at least going to remind you that it's not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Do you think it is possible to embed the Icecast server into an application in a way that it can still be submitted into the Mac App Store?

Also, is there a library for Objective-C that allows me to stream to an Icecast server?

Comment: I know that Nicecast does something like that. They bundle their own Icecast build and provide its sources/patches upon request (for compliance). Please be sure to comply with the Icecast license though (GPLv2). Currently known programming language bindings of libshout are listed here: http://icecast.org/download/#bindings  -- I'm not familiar with Objective-C, but it might just be able to use libshout as a C library directly.