# Keeping socket open after HTTP request/response to Node.js server

Tags: http, node.js

To support a protocol (Icecast Source Protocol) based on HTTP, I need to be able to use a socket from Node.js's http.Server once the HTTP request is finished.  A sample request looks like this:

```
Client->Server: GET / HTTP/1.0
Client->Server: Some-Headers:header_value
Client->Server: 
Server->Client: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server->Client: 
Client->Server: <insert stream of binary data here>
```

This is to support the source of an internet radio stream, the source of the stream data being the client in this case.

Is there any way I can use Node.js's built in http.Server?  I have tried this:

```
this.server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('connection!');
    res.writeHead(200, {test: 'woot!'});
    res.write('test');
    res.write('test2');
    req.connection.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

If I telnet into port 1337 and make a request, I am able to see the first couple characters of what I type on the server console window, but then the server closes the connection.  Ideally, I'd keep that socket open indefinitely, and take the HTTP part out of the loop once the initial request is made.

Is this possible with the stock http.Server class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to reinvent the wheel and write my own HTTP-ish server.  Not perfect, but it works.  Hopefully the innards of some of these stock Node.js classes will be exposed some day.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is reporting `HTTP/1.0` as the protocol version the server is probably closing the connection. If your client is something you have control over, you might want to try to set the keep alive header (`Connection: Keep-Alive` is the right one I think).

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation, here's how I got it to work:

```
http.createServer(function(res, req){

// Prepare the response headers

res.writeHead(200);

// Flush the headers to socket

res._send('');

// Inform http.serverResponse instance that we've sent the headers

res._headerSent = true;

}).listen(1234);
```

The socket will now remain open, as no http.serverResponse.end() has been called, but the headers have been flushed.

If you want to send response data (not that you'll need to for an Icecast source connection), simply:

```
res.write(buffer_or_string);
res._send('');
```

When closing the connection just call `res.end()`.

I have successfully streamed MP3 data using this method, but haven't tested it under stress.