# OS X icecast source connect to server and stream mp3 in Objective-C or C/C++

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, streaming, icecast

I need to write an source application for icecast streaming for os x. Problem is that I have no idea how to connect to icecast server and start to streaming data. I was going through internet for a while and I haven't found an answer how to connect to server (with user and password) and then start to stream data.

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9985297/362536

Comment: i have done it by using libshout library, it is very easy to use and solved all my problems