# send Stream Data to icecast

Tags: java, sockets, stream, icecast, internet-radio

i want to develop client that bind to icecast server just like butt or edcast but using java, I've found some library like jshout,libshout but I cant make it work in windows ;(, so I'm thinking not depend to some library, I got some information how to stream to icecast server from this link [Icecast 2: protocol description, streaming to it using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215019/icecast-2-protocol-description-streaming-to-it-using-c-sharp) , my question is how o send the binary stream data to icecast server? should i using socket or there's another way to do that?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple HTTP 1.1 PUT request (just for now without chunked encoding) if you are running Icecast 2.4.0 or newer.
Once the connection is established, you just keep sending data from your encoder/muxer.
If you want to know what headers to send etc, then looking at libshout sources should help.