# Send data via Android on IceCast2

Tags: java, android, stream, server, icecast

Good afternoon! It is necessary to know, how can I send data (audio stream) to the server via Icecast2 written application me. In general, I need a code through which I can send data to the server with the Android phone. Who can, please describe in detail. Thank you!

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9985297/362536  However, more recent versions of Icecast (>=2.4 I believe) support normal HTTP PUT requests.  No need for the `SOURCE` method anymore.