# How to write to Icecast mount point with avformat (ffmpeg)?

Tags: ffmpeg, icecast, libavformat

I'm building a program (I want to use libavformat not ffmpeg executable) to stream live video to Icecast server and it looks like FFmpeg should be able to do it. I can write the live video to a file (which is not really simple to begin with :) ) but I can't find simple code / example to how to use avformat/avio to write to Icecast (network) mount point.
Any pointers to example code would be appreciated.

Comment: A bit dated, but see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9985297/362536  These days it's even easier... you can use an HTTP PUT request instead of a SOURCE request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was easy. You just open the output URL as this where "xxx:yyy" is the user and the password for the mount :

```
const char *outputfile = "icecast://xxx:yyy@10.0.0.1:8000/xyz.mkv";
out_format = av_guess_format(NULL, outputfile, NULL);
```

You might need to set the content type:

```
av_dict_set(&out_options, "content_type", "video/x-matroska", 0);
```

Then you just open the URL:

```
avio_open2(&out_fctx->pb, outputfile, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, NULL, &out_options) < 0);
```

It's tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

When using FFmpeg, you specify the output as an icecast:// URL:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -content-type video/webm icecast://user:password@hostname.tld/mountpoint
```

It's unclear if you are using ffmpeg or libavformat directly; if there's a way to specify a URL for output in the latter case, though, just preface it with icecast:// I would assume.

Another option is to use [libshout](http://www.icecast.org/download/) instead; it's a library designed for sending streams to an Icecast server at the appropriate rate.

Comment: That's why I said that I'm building a program (not using ffmpeg executable). And libshout is a mess to compile under windows. I don't even want to get into that :)