# Make iOS device as source client using Icecast

Tags: ios, swift, icecast

I want to make `iOS` device as source client to send the audio to `icecast` server. I have setup the `icecast` server on `localhost` successfully. Right now when I send below request to server it creates the `mountpoint` but only for first `8 sec` of the `audio`, the total length of `audio` is `25 sec`. I know this is because I'm not sending the data in chunks. Below is my request:

```
let requestString = "http://localhost:8000/"
let url = URL(string: requestString)
let mountPointName = "myMountPoint"

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "SOURCE /\(mountPointName) ICE/1.0"
request.addValue("SOURCE /mp3test ICE/1.0", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOURCE")
request.addValue("audio/ogg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("Basic c291cmNlOmhhY2ttZQ==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("Server name", forHTTPHeaderField: "ice-name")
request.setValue("https://www.google.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "ice-url")
request.setValue("RockTest", forHTTPHeaderField: "ice-genre")
request.setValue("128", forHTTPHeaderField: "ice-bitrate")
request.setValue("0", forHTTPHeaderField: "ice-private")
request.setValue("1", forHTTPHeaderField: "ice-public")
request.setValue("Server description", forHTTPHeaderField: "ice-description")
request.setValue("samplerate=44100;bitrate=128;channels=2", forHTTPHeaderField: "ice-audio-info")
self.recurseivelySendRequest(request)
```

**My recursive function:**

```
func recurseivelySendRequest(_ _request: URLRequest) {
    var request = _request

    do {
        let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mount", withExtension: "ogg")  let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL!)
        let inputStream = InputStream(data: data)
        request.httpBodyStream = inputStream
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

   // let dataTask = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request)
   // dataTask.resume()

   let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

   if (error != nil) {
       print(error ?? "error = unknown")
       return
   }

   print(response ?? "response = unknown")

   do {
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
      print(json)
   } catch let error {
      print(error)
      let str = String.init(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
      print(str ?? "str = nil")
   }

   self.recurseivelySendRequest(request)
}
        dataTask.resume()
}
```

The problem with above code is it sends only few part of the `audio` also If I don't send the request recursively the `mountpoint` no longer exists and seems it is replacing the data not adding. So what I want is to create the `mountpoint` once and then write the audio data in chunks.

I also followed [Icecast 2: protocol description, streaming to it using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215019/icecast-2-protocol-description-streaming-to-it-using-c-sharp/9985297#9985297)

Comment: What the heck are you doing there? Your mountpoint is named "mp3test", you indicate content "audio/ogg" and send headers indicating CBR?

Comment: @TBR Actually I copied it from [this description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215019/icecast-2-protocol-description-streaming-to-it-using-c-sharp/9985297#9985297).

Comment: That description is consistent for sending the old MP3 content aka "audio/mpeg". You changed that. What codec are you using?

Comment: Oh yes my mistake this was "audio/mpeg"... I'm trying to send the data from a locally stored audio file by converting it into `data`. I'm not encoding it.

Comment: If you claim audio/ogg, but send something else, the server will drop you quickly. One of the reasons I'm prodding this.

Comment: Probably I'm wrong and I will correct this. But right now I'm able to create the `mountpoint` for initial part of the `audio`. Is it possible to create a `mountpoint` and sending the audio data later whenever I want?

Comment: No, are you sure you understand how Icecast works? Icecast is a **live** streaming server. http://liveice.sourceforge.net/understanding.html It takes a continuous stream of binary data and clients can connect to it and will be served **live** data from that point in time.

Comment: Okay! But there is no guarantee to stream the audio continuously obviously there will be a lack. And should I have to send the all meta data info every time when audio will be send? I'm confused!! And Unfortunately the link you provided is dead :|

Comment: Works for me, seems it was a transient server problem with SourceForge. - While you can set overrides, each source client connection is supposed to set up Metadata. If you need continuous availability, you can provide a "fallback". For details please see https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/

Comment: @TBR Thanks for your valuable time! Finally its working now.

Comment: @TBR There is a delay in voice upto 5-10 seconds.. any suggestion for this?

Comment: That kind of delay is par for the course. A minimum delay of around 1 second is expected. 5-10s is normal. Tuning it down to a minimum comes at the expense of connection robustness and requires a well performing network. There are very few reasons to tune it this way. More often it indicates that a different tool/transport should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on wrong path finally I found [iOS-Icecast-Client](https://github.com/gstream/iOS-Icecast-Client) on github. It helps me to make a connection with `icecast-server` and send the recorder audio to server in chunks. As I have already mentioned that I was able to setup the `icecast-server` on `localhost`.

After downloading the above library in `AudioProcessor.m` file there is a line

```
ShoutOutputStream_Init("192.x.x.x", 8000, "/stream", "source", "hackme", 0);
```

Where `192.x.x.x` is your wifi ip as you can not use `localhost` in device to connect it. Also make sure your system and device should be on same wifi connection to reach the network.

`8000` is your port defined in `icecast.xml`.

`/stream` is mount point name defined in `icecast.xml`.

And here comes where I spent few hours to get the `username` and `password` these are also defined in `authentication` tag in `icecast.xml`. I used the default one `source` and `hackme`.

`0` is whether it is `vorbis` (0) or a `.mp3` (1) file.

Finally I got it working. And Many thanks to [gstream79](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5756697/gstream79) to provide us such a wonderful library.